# How to connect HTML5 pages to back-end?

Tags: database, html, backend

I am totally new to HTML5.

Previously I have developed Silverlight and ASP .Net applications.

My question is :

How do I develop a HTML5-based website, with login for users, and pages that show data from a back-end database ?

Can I develop this using Visual Studio 2010 ?

What do I use as my backend that connects to the database ?

Do you have ANY samples at all you can link to here ?

Comment: HTML/HTML5 is just used to display text & media to the end-user. You still need everything else to build a web application. You need CSS for styling. JavaScript for some dynamic content. You need a database; Most commonly used for this task is the PHP/MySQL combination because of the cost (you can't beat 'free') and the ease of setup (it's usually already set up when you buy web hosting).

Comment: So long as you have the skills required to build, you could use any IDE that supports web development. I think Aptana is very popular for this. Here is the link: http://www.aptana.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally recommend asp net MVC3 for this kind of thing (with razor). You can put small tags into already valid HTML (HTML 5 included)

I would also use the entity framework for accessing Databases (I think it works with multiple providers, so SQL Server, My SQL, Oracle, etc). It makes it very simple.

You said you have worked with ASP before, but I will include a great set of tutorials at

http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/Courses/TableOfContents?courseName=aspdotnet-mvc3-intro

You can do this in VS2010, and backend would be the Entity framework.

If you have never used MVC before, its one of those things where once you get it, you wont want to do it any other way.

Comment: Does Visual Studio 2010 SP1 have a built-in template for building HTML5 websites as the front-end ?

Comment: Razor just injects your code into HTML. I could (in theory) take any HTML website and throw it right into an MVC Razor project. Razor does not use a WYSIWYG Html editor. It comes with a prebuilt template that contains a login control and tabs. The included template is not HTML5 ready, but it could be easily modified